# Using images as turtle shape

Tags: python

I have been struggling with something probably very simple.
I am trying to insert an image as turtle shape but an error keeps always there.

My code is

```
 import turtle

 shape_2 = turtle.Shape('image', 'exemple.gif')
 turtle.register_shape('play', shape_2)
 turtle.shape('play')
 turtle.forward(100)
 turtle.left(45)
 turtle.forward(50)
```

the error is

```
[evaluate testee.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Utilizador/Desktop/Python/testee.py", line 3, in <module>
    shape_2 = turtle.Shape('image', 'exemple.gif')
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Anaconda3\Lib\turtle.py", line 886, in __init__
    data = TurtleScreen._image(data)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Anaconda3\Lib\turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3539, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Utilizador\Anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3483, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError('Too early to create image')
builtins.RuntimeError: Too early to create image
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Tkinter Error, "Too Early to Create Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236857/python-tkinter-error-too-early-to-create-image)

Answer (score 1):

You can register a `.gif` file shape directly:

```
import turtle

play = 'example.gif'

turtle.register_shape(play)
turtle.shape(play)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(45)
turtle.forward(50)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alan, It is now working fine, do you know why it was not working before with the turtle.Shape?

Comment: To be honest I'm not really sure, but I noticed that when you create a `turtle.Shape()` object, the code that is executed inside Turtle is `TurtleScreen._image(name)`. When you register as I suggested, it's `self._image(name)`. I suspect It's because the `Screen` singleton is not instantiated when you use `turtle.Shape(...)` directly