# I am getting an error when I try to upload an image on tkinter using label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting an error when I am trying to upload an image using tkinter
I have downloaded a gif image and saved it on a file named "image.gif" and saved the picture as "image"

```
#Add a picture using label

logo = PhotoImage(file="img.gif")

w1 = Label(news_window, image=logo).pack(side="right")

w2 = Label(news_window, 
              justify=RIGHT,
              padx = 10, 
              text=explanation).pack(side="right")
```

The error message I get is "Permission denied"

Comment: Type that exact error into the stackoverflow search box and you'll find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> You forgot to declare root - root = Tk(). The Tk system must be ON before using it.

[Python Tkinter Error, "Too Early to Create Image"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236857/python-tkinter-error-too-early-to-create-image)